# How can I modify an auth_token of a redis cluster if the redis engine version is below 5.0.5?

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis

I am running a redis cluster on AWS with engine version 5.0.3.

So when I tried to use this aws command to modify the auth_token

```
aws elasticache modify-replication-group \ 
--replication-group-id authtestgroup \ 
--auth-token This-is-the-set-token\ 
--auth-token-update-strategy SET \ 
--apply-immediately
```

I got this error:  `An error occurred (InvalidParameterValue) when calling the ModifyReplicationGroup operation: The AUTH token modification is only supported for redis engine version 5.0.5 and above.`

Is there any way I can modify the auth_token short of destroying and recreate the redis cluster?

I just want to learn if there is any known workaround to this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you pointed out, prior to Redis 5.0.5, changing the `AUTH` token was not supported.  The only way I found to do this is to stand up a replacement cluster, which at that point you should upgrade the Redis version.

#### References

- [Amazon Elasticache Announces Support for Modifying Redis AUTH](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/10/amazon-elasticache-announces-support-for-modifying-redis-authentication-tokens/)
- [Redis Password Change](https://www.reddit.com/r/aws/comments/acoa0i/elasticache_with_redis_password_change/)